# how does index i work as local and index iterable in python?

Tags: python

I dont see why this code produces '11', how does the char work as iterable "i" index and value at the same time?

```py
chars = "1234"
char = ""
for char in reversed(chars):
    char += char

print(char)
```

Comment: I suggest stepping through this code line-by-line in a debugger, on paper, or in your head, to determine what's happening at each step.

Comment: In the last iteration, `char` is initally `'1'`. Then you reassign `char` to `char + char`, giving you `'11'`. Then you print this value.

Comment: The `for` loop resets `char` each iteration. Thus only the final iteration of the loop is meaningful and that takes `"1"` and appends `"1"` to it resulting in `"11"`

Comment: In each iteration, the for loop is replacing the value of char, so in the last iteration, char is '1' and that's because you get '11'

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what's happening, step by step.

First, the setup:

```
chars = "1234"
char = ""
```

Now, the loop starts:

```
for char in reversed(chars)
# equivalent to: for char in reversed("1234")
# equivalent to: for char in "4321":
```

So now, because we put the variable `char` in the for loop, the value of `char` is going to be overwritten on each loop iteration, equivalent to:

```
char = "4"
```

Now, we're adding it to itself, which will result in the character doubled:

```
char += char
# equivalent to: "4" + "4"
# which equals "44"
# therefore:
char = "44"
```

Now for the next iteration, because we have `char` in the for loop, its value is now assigned to the next item in the list (thus clearing out its previous value):

```
char = "3"
```

Then we just continue on:

```
char += char
"3" + "3" = "33"
```

```
char = "2"
char += char
"2" + "2" = "22"
```

```
char = "1"
char += char
"1" + "1" = "11"
```

Now, the loop is over, so we move past it

```
print(char)
# equivalent to print("11")
```

output:

```
11
```